# Convert JSONArray to ArrayList<class> using Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

Since I'm relatively new to Android development as well as Java (and its thousands of different free libraries), I'm currently struggling to get an `ArrayList<>` of a custom class out of a `JSONArray`.

I'm using loopj `AsyncHttpClient` and Jackson to fetch JSON data from an API, deserialize it and bind it to an `ArrayAdapter`.

```
ArrayList<Transcoder> data = new ArrayList<Transcoder>;
ApiRestClient.get("transcoder", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(JSONArray entities) {
        data = JsonUtils.getObjectMapper().readValues(entities, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Transcoder>>() {});
    }
...
```

Now, this obviously doesn't work since the object mapper surprisingly doesn't take "`JSONArray`" as a parameter. How can I make this work? Flatten the `JSONArray` to string? Or getting the `JSONArray` content within a foreach loop?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from passing `entities.toString()` to the `ObjectMapper` object.

Comment: @Luksprog Straight-forward. OK. I thought there may be a different approach since it's a little bit unnecessary because the JSONArray was constructed out of a string from the http response.

Comment: I don't know the API you are using, but, if possible, just don't construct a JSONArray in the first place. Pass the String directly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The API is my own from a different project. The call "onSuccess" which I'm overriding is from the loopj Async Http library, so no - I can't change that. :)